# how to process static data in AMAZON Kinesis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

How can we process static data in Amazon kinesis?
For example I have data in excel sheets and I want to process them in Kinesis. Is it possible? If yes then how to achieve it ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please provide more information about the solution you are trying to implement? Amazon Kinesis is designed for receiving and storing streaming data. Please let us know more about why you wish to use Kinesis for "static" data. If you can provide more information about what you are trying to achieve, we might be able to recommend better alternatives.

Comment: Thank you John. The solution will be meant for consuming real time streaming data. However, there are situation where we need to consume offline excel files and we don't want to change the architecture/tool/product etc. Is there any way by which we can consume the offline excel using Kinesis stream or Kinesis firehese??

Comment: Maybe you mean to ask about event processing and not necessarily event streaming. AWS Lambda is a good framework for event triggers. For example, you can trigger a Lambda function when you put a new Excel file in S3, and your Lambda code can read the file content and process these records (or put them into Kinesis Firehose after some transformations).

Answer (score 1):

**Amazon Kinesis** receives information from [Producers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/amazon-kinesis-producers.html). When producers send information to a Kinesis stream, they specify the name of the stream, a partition key, and the data blob to be added to the stream.

You must either call Kinesis directly, or use the [Kinesis Producer Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/developing-producers-with-kpl.html), which simplifies the process (eg batching records to make less calls).

If you wish to send data from an Excel spreadsheet to a Kinesis stream, **you will need to write a producer application** that reads the data from the spreadsheet and sends it to Kinesis.